# Showing that if $B\in \langle A \rangle$ is invertible then $B^{-1}\in \langle A \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem I'm a bit stuck:

> Let $\langle A \rangle
>  =\{c_0A^k+c_1A^{k-1}+\cdots+c_{k-1}A+c_kI\;|\;c_i\in K\}$. Given that $A^{-1}\in \langle A \rangle$, show that if an invertible matrix $B\in
>  \langle A \rangle$ then $B^{-1}\in \langle A \rangle$.

How should I proceed? $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(K)$, where $K$ is a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A^{-1}$ equals a polynomial in $A$ of degree $n$, then $A$ satisfies a polynomial equation of degree $n+1$.  So $\langle A\rangle$ has dimension $n+1$.
$I,B,B^2,B^3,...$ are all vectors in this $n+1$-dimensional space.

Comment: Thank you for your help 

Comment: One more question. In order to prove the problem I need to show $B^{-1}$ has the form $B^{-1}=b_oA^{k}+\dots+b_{k-1}A+b_kI$ correct?